# I'm having error with cv2.findContours (...)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I'm making a code and cannot get use the function cv2.findContours, because have any problem with it. Follow the code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lower1 = np.array([0,118,0])
upper1 = np.array([120,198,166])
lower2 = np.array([45,0,0])
upper2 = np.array([70,255,255])
kernelOpen = np.ones((7,7))
kernelClose = np.ones((20,20))

img = cv2.imread ('inco.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower1, upper1)
res1 = cv2.bitwise_not(img, img, mask = mask1)
cv2.imwrite('resultado_bitwise_not.png', res1)

img1 = cv2.imread ('resultado_bitwise_not.png')
hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv2, lower2, upper2)
res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask = mask2)
cv2.imwrite('resultado_final.png', res2)

mask3 = cv2.morphologyEx (res2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
mask4 = cv2.morphologyEx (mask3, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)

_, conts, h = cv2.findContours(mask4, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, conts, -1,(0,255,0),3)


cv2.imwrite('mask4.png',mask4)
```

And the error:

```
_, conts, h = cv2.findContours(mask4, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:199: error: (-210) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function cvStartFindContours_Impl
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that "*FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images*". You are trying to force an image (mask4) which is not a binary image (CV_8UC1) in the input field of findContours function. Your inRange function created a binary image in both the areas  of your code. But later when you used bitwise_and and bitwise_not operators with an rgb image, the output changed into an image which is no more binary. Please take a look at this [example](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) to find out what happens when you do a bitwise operation between a binary image and a color image. This is the root of all issues. Try to weed out this conflict, your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

As Arun Kumar stated you ought to pass a binary image (0 and 1) to the function `cv2.findContours()`.

The image `mask2` is what you should be processing after obtaining it from the line `mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv2, lower2, upper2)`. It is the binary image. The following changes can be made to get the desired result:

```
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv2, lower2, upper2)

#--- replacing res2 with mask2 ---
mask3 = cv2.morphologyEx (mask2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
mask4 = cv2.morphologyEx (mask3, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)

_, conts, h = cv2.findContours(mask4, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, conts, -1,(0,255,0),3)

#--- you must write img not mask4 to see the contours on the original image---
cv2.imwrite('mask4.png', img)
```

If you want the masked portion only:

```
res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask = mask4)
cv2.imwrite('resultado_final.png', res2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your input image before using `cv2.findContours` with:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

new_image = np.uint8(old_image)  # convert to uint8
```

and then:

```
_, conts, h = cv2.findContours(new_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```